# Pandas time series add column showing 1 hour intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I can create an hour of day column in Pandas using `data['hod'] = [r.hour for r in data.index]` which is really useful for groupby related analysis.  However, I would like to be able to create a similar column for 1 hour intervals starting at 09:30 instead of 09:00. So the column values would be 09:30-10:30, 10:30-11:30 etc.

The aim is to be able to groupby these values in order to gain stats for the time period.

Using data as follows.  I already added hour of day, day of week etc, I just need the same for time sliced from 09:30 onwards in one hour intervals:

```
data['2008-05-06 09:00:00':].head()


Open    High    Low Last    Volume  hod dow dom minute
Timestamp                                   
2008-05-06 09:00:00 1399.50 1399.50 1399.25 1399.50 4   9   1   6   0
2008-05-06 09:01:00 1399.25 1399.75 1399.25 1399.50 5   9   1   6   1
2008-05-06 09:02:00 1399.75 1399.75 1399.00 1399.50 19  9   1   6   2
2008-05-06 09:03:00 1399.50 1399.75 1398.50 1398.50 37  9   1   6   3
2008-05-06 09:04:00 1398.75 1399.00 1398.75 1398.75 15  9   1   6   4
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail.  This just gives me output  `DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')`

Comment: @adele, can you post desired data set?

Comment: Hi Maxu, I just need something I can use to groupby in a similar way I do for each standard hour in the following example `data['2016'].groupby('hod').Volume.mean()` where hod is generated by `[r.hour for r in data.index]`.  If this means I need a new column called something like "non std hour interval" showing 09:30-10:30, 10:30-11:30 etc that would be fine.  If there is another way to do my groupby to capture 09:30-10:30 etc that is also great.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You can change the `periods` to the number of rows you want to keep. Something like: `df['non std hour interval'] = pd.date_range('5/6/2008 09:30:00', periods=100, freq='H')`. If `df` is your original `dataframe`.

Comment: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`  I tried your suggestion @Nickil Maveli but get this error. `len(data)` gives output `2856658` and these are 1 minute bars so how would i set the correct periods using your approach?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that when you start from half point of each hour then you divide a day into 25 sections instead of 24. Here is how I labelled those sections: Section -1: [0:00, 0:29], Section 0: [0:30, 1:29], Section 1: [1:30, 2:29] ... Section 22: [22:30, 23:29] and Section 23: [23:30, 23:50], where first and last sections are half an hour long.

And here is an implementation with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def shifted_hour_of_day(ts, beginning_of_hour=0):
    shift = pd.Timedelta('%dmin' % (beginning_of_hour))
    ts_shifted = ts - pd.Timedelta(shift)
    hour = ts_shifted.hour
    if ts_shifted.day != ts.day:  # we shifted these timestamps to yesterday
        hour = -1  # label the first section as -1
    return hour

# Generate random data
timestamps = pd.date_range('2008-05-06 00:00:00', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', freq='10min')
vals = np.random.rand(len(timestamps))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=timestamps, data={'value': vals})
df.loc[:, 'hod'] = [r.hour for r in df.index]
# Test shifted_hour_of_day
df.loc[:, 'hod2'] = [shifted_hour_of_day(r, beginning_of_hour=20) for r in df.index]
df.head(20)
```

Now you can groupby this DataFrame on 'hod2'.